# is printf privileged instruction?

Tags: io, printf, instructions, kernel-mode, usermode

since I/O instructions are privileged instructions that require mode switch from user to kernel, is printf also considered a privileged instruction? is there mode switch when performing printf instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is printf also considered a privileged instruction?

No, the `printf` is not privileged, nor an instruction, it is a function call.

> is there mode switch when performing printf [function calls]?

Yes, eventually inside printf it will do a [write function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) call and that will pass over to kernel mode. Note however, because of buffering, the pass to kernel mode may not happen on the first `printf` call, and may be delayed until buffers are full or `fflush` is called.